# How to solve Keychain error: Implicit conversion of C pointer type 'CFTypeRef'

Tags: ios, objective-c, keychain

I am trying this [Using the Keychain to store passwords on iOS](http://b2cloud.com.au/how-to-guides/using-the-keychain-to-store-passwords-on-ios) with **storybored** to store user **email** and **password** for login.

In my m file:

```
....
....
#import "KeychainItemWrapper.m"
....
....
KeychainItemWrapper* keychain = [[KeychainItemWrapper alloc] initWithIdentifier:@"KeychainTest" accessGroup:nil];
        [keychain setObject:kSecAttrAccessibleWhenUnlocked forKey:kSecAttrAccessible];

        NSLog(@"%@, %@", [keychain objectForKey:kSecAttrAccount], [keychain objectForKey:kSecValueData]);

        [keychain setObject:@"example@email.com" forKey:kSecAttrAccount];
        [keychain setObject:@"MySuperSecretPassword" forKey:kSecValueData];

        NSLog(@"%@, %@", [keychain objectForKey:kSecAttrAccount], [keychain objectForKey:kSecValueData]);
```

but I am getting the following errors:

```
Implicit conversion of C pointer type 'CFTypeRef' (aka 'const void *') to Objective-C pointer type 'id' requires a bridged cast
```

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I already answered this in your other post.
[Is there an Android sharedpreferences equivalent in iOS to save credentials (Username and Password)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21176201/is-there-an-android-sharedpreferences-equivalent-in-ios-to-save-credentials-use)

I'll repost it here:

This happens because you are probably using "ARC". Are you? If so, you can set a flag to ignore ARC for that specific file. Select your project, Select your target, select Build Phases and expand the "Compile Sources" drop down. Look for KeychainItemWrapper (or whatever you call your keychain file) and set this flag. -fno-objc-arc

Comment: now i am getting this error on kSecAttrAccessible, kSecValueData, kSecAttrAccount, kSecValueData and kSecValueData. I don't understand what is this error

Comment: I would recommend a Keychain Wrapper that is already optimized for ARC.  Something like this should do you good. http://www.thomasverbeek.com/blog/?p=351.

Comment: it has many errors, i am using this https://github.com/kamiro/SFHFKeychainUtils instead but I am getting another error "clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
"

Comment: Great!!  Glad you got it figured out!  It was a pain when i first started out with it too.

Comment: It didn't work, I thought it did, still getting this error "clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)"  when adding "#import "SFHFKeychainUtils.m"" :(

Comment: Fixed it should import "SFHFKeychainUtils.h" not "SFHFKeychainUtils.m"